# Browser Based Server Monitor Package For Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-monitor

I have been researching a package for Ubuntu 16.04 (I've seen some) that will serve as a Monitor for hardware and traffic. I have seen Monitorix, but just tried to install it the other night (on ubuntu 16.04) and had installation issues. I will try it again, but in the mean-time:

I am looking for something cross browser-based, and with the ability to monitor everything from Hardware to traffic.

Monitor:

CPU(s)
Hard-Drive(s)
Fan(s) 
Incoming Traffic by IP
etc..etc..etc..

Basically, an easy to follow Server Monitor Package for the beginner web hosting administrator using Ubuntu Server. I would like to start with a package that will be easy enough for me to follow, yet robust for expansion to more powerful server equipment! I would like to know when I truly need to upgrade new server equipment from this package.

A Simple yet robust monitoring package (for Ubuntu server) for the brand new web-hosting administrator who plans on expanding from a small to mid-size server in the future.

Thank you
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Update: I have installed Monitorix using the monitorix website instructions, adding the izzysoft repo. and following the rest of that tutorial works on Ubuntu 16.04. But after quickly using it, I find it kind of difficult to figure out what each thing means...I know this is a common issue for first-timers, but to make a monitor tool (package) for ubuntu that clearly identifies what is being monitored like:

CPU Temp: 140 Degrees Currently / 300 Degrees max!
Hard Drive (/sda) ======= 10% worn out!
Ram: ======= 10% worn out!

Something that uses progress bars to identify when the equipment needs replacing would be fantastic!

I know the above examples are fictitious, but the idea here is simplicity to understand so one will know that when the cpu reaches 300 Degrees for example they should replace the cpu, likewise when the hard drive (sda1) is starting to wear, (example cylinders) are 10% worn out, it shows a progress bar (that when hit's 80, needs replacement), and same for the ram. Also, for traffic, so and other important stuff. Basically this would be like a Monitor for Dummies...

For Developers, you will be *loved* for this kind of package! It's quite difficult as it is to keep up with a server, a really simple monitoring package (like above) would hit the spot.

Thank you
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using some opensource/free monitoring tool? I started some time ago using one called "Pandora FMS", it is web browser based, and it can help you monitor easily a lot of operating system level stuff. It requires a small software component installed on your system, but it allows you to gather data and build bar-like graphs as you need.

You have other tools like Nagios, but I found this one a bit harder to "put to work" and to understand, also with a learning-curve quite sharp.

Feel free to ask if you need some additional info :)

Regards!